# Redis Local.xml file setup help

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, xml, redis

where do I add this redis code for it to work in my local.xml?

`<cache>
  <backend>Cm_Cache</backend>
  <backend_options>
    <server>127.0.0.1</server> 
    <port>6379</port>
    <persistent></persistent> 
    <password></password> 
    <force_standalone>0</force_standalone>

    <connect_retries>1</connect_retries>

    <read_timeout>10</read_timeout>

    <automatic_cleaning_factor>0</automatic_cleaning_factor> 
    <compress_data>1</compress_data>

    <compress_tags>1</compress_tags>

    <compress_threshold>20480</compress_threshold>

    <compression_lib>gzip</compression_lib> 
    <use_lua>0</use_lua> 
  </backend_options>
</cache>`

here is my local.xml:

config
global, are not showing but they are there.

`

```
    <install>
        <date><![CDATA[Thu, 13 Nov 2014 16:42:08 +0000]]></date>
    </install>
    <crypt>
        <key><![CDATA[**************************]]></key>
    </crypt>
    <disable_local_modules>false</disable_local_modules>
    <resources>
        <db>
            <table_prefix><![CDATA[]]></table_prefix>
        </db>
        <default_setup>
            <connection>
                <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
                <username><![CDATA[appuser]]></username>
                <password><![CDATA[**********]]></password>
                <dbname><![CDATA[******]]></dbname>
                <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
                <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
                <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
                <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
                <active>1</active>
            </connection>
        </default_setup>
    </resources>
    <session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save>
</global>
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <frontName><![CDATA[g******]]></frontName>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add redis configuration just after `<global>` tag. And your local.xml should looks like below mentioned code.

```
<config>
    <global>
        <cache>
          <backend>Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis</backend>
          <backend_options>
            <server>127.0.0.1</server>
            <port>6379</port>
            <persistent></persistent>
            <database>0</database>
            <password></password>
            <force_standalone>0</force_standalone>
            <connect_retries>1</connect_retries>
            <read_timeout>10</read_timeout>
            <automatic_cleaning_factor>0</automatic_cleaning_factor>
            <compress_data>1</compress_data>
            <compress_tags>1</compress_tags>
            <compress_threshold>20480</compress_threshold>
            <compression_lib>gzip</compression_lib>
            <use_lua>0</use_lua>
          </backend_options>
        </cache>
        <full_page_cache>
          <backend>Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis</backend>
          <backend_options>
            <server>127.0.0.1</server>
            <port>6379</port>
            <persistent></persistent>
            <database>1</database>
            <password></password>
            <force_standalone>0</force_standalone>
            <connect_retries>1</connect_retries>
            <lifetimelimit>57600</lifetimelimit>
            <compress_data>0</compress_data>
          </backend_options>
        </full_page_cache>
        <!--End caching-->
        <install>
        <date><![CDATA[Thu, 13 Nov 2014 16:42:08 +0000]]></date>
        </install>
        <crypt>
            <key><![CDATA[**************************]]></key>
        </crypt>
        <disable_local_modules>false</disable_local_modules>
        <resources>
            <db>
                <table_prefix><![CDATA[]]></table_prefix>
            </db>
            <default_setup>
                <connection>
                    <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
                    <username><![CDATA[appuser]]></username>
                    <password><![CDATA[**********]]></password>
                    <dbname><![CDATA[******]]></dbname>
                    <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
                    <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
                    <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
                    <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
                    <active>1</active>
                </connection>
            </default_setup>
        </resources>
        <session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save>
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <frontName><![CDATA[g******]]></frontName>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

For check redis is working with your setup.

Login with your terminal :

```
$redis-cli
```

Press enter and you should look like below mentioned

```
127.0.0.1:6379>keys *
```

Press enter and you should see magento class names block name in caching.

Result should look something like attached screen shot.

[image]